# Center a div, and then have a nav fixed next to it

Tags: css, position, css-position

I need a centered 960px `<div>`. Then I need a 100px `<nav>` to appear fixed and on the left of the 960px div. So the `<nav>` is always in view, and touching the centered 960px `<div>`.

How can I do this?

jsFiddle that is close: http://jsfiddle.net/hcsJ9/

The main issue here is that the nav needs to be touching the 960px div. Not touching the edge of the browser. Try resizing your browser horizontally to see how it sticks to the window not the content.

The 960px div must be centered. You cannot put both in a 960px div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could quite easily do it like this: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/Gtzqu

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: -250px;
}

.centered300 {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.item {
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}


</style>

</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <p>Link 1</p>
    <p>Link 2</p>
    <p>Link 3</p>
</nav>

<section class="centered300">
    <div class="item">
        <p>Hello I'm a bunch of page content. I say random stuff blah blah blah.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p>Hello I'm a bunch of page content. I say random stuff blah blah blah.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p>Hello I'm a bunch of page content. I say random stuff blah blah blah.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p>Hello I'm a bunch of page content. I say random stuff blah blah blah.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p>Hello I'm a bunch of page content. I say random stuff blah blah blah.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p>Hello I'm a bunch of page content. I say random stuff blah blah blah.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p>Hello I'm a bunch of page content. I say random stuff blah blah blah.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p>Hello I'm a bunch of page content. I say random stuff blah blah blah.</p>
    </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly. But, your best bet would be to float the nav and 960 div next to each other and then center that. Fiddle coming shortly.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/wuPHQ/1/

```
<div id="holder">
    <div id="nav">Navigation</div>
    <div id="content">Content</div>
    <br clear="all" />
</div>


#holder {
    width: 1060px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

#nav {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#content {
    width: 960px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: However, that would un-center the div by 50px. So maybe add 100px right padding on the holder to even it out?